# It prints DATA when displaying the value of variable with type array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I can't understand why cout prints DATA for str variable. str does not contain the memory address of the first caracter ? What does it mean DATA ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    char str[7]=”DATA”;

    cout << str[2]<<” “<<str;

    return 0;

}
```

It prints T DATA.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: `operator<<` have overload for `const char*` which display as string, and not as pointer.

Comment: what do you think that bits header does? why that using statement? what are those quote marks? why no newline on your output statement?

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<` has an overload for `const char*` that prints out characters until it hits a null terminating character. And a `char[]` array decays into a `char*` pointer to its 1st element.

So, when we print `str[2]` it just prints the single character `T`, but when we print `str` it prints all of the characters.

Comment: this does not really explain the problem

Comment: @NeilButterworth it does now

Answer (score 0):

`str[2]` is a single `char`, `T`, which you see.

`str`, on the other hand, is a `char*` (read: pointer to `char`), and `cout` will print it as a c-string - i.e., print all the characters until it reaches the null character (`\0`), similar to what `printf` would have done. If you don't want that overload, you could cast it to a `void*`:

```cpp
cout << str[2] << " " << (void* ) str;
```

Comment: "*`str` ... is a `char*`*" - technically, `str` is a `char[]` array that *decays* into a `char*` pointer in certain contexts, such as when passed by value in a function parameter.